# Javascript: Why this code doesn´t work?

Tags: javascript

This snippet doesn´t work. I´m trying to get the file size of an resource via jscript

I find this code:

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
obj.open('HEAD', 'resource.png', true);

obj.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(obj.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if(obj.status == 200) 
        {
            alert('Size in bytes: ' + obj.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    }
};
```

Whats wrong? thanks.

Comment: What does not work? You never call send...

Comment: `'POST'` or `'GET'`. What's `'HEAD'`? Also, `.getResponseHeader()` may not work on all Browsers. What about `obj.send()`?

Comment: @PHPglue The HTTP `HEAD` method is used to request *only* the headers.  It's response is expected to be identical for the same request using the `GET` method, minus the content-body of the response.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
obj.open('HEAD', 'resource.png', true);

obj.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(obj.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if(obj.status == 200) 
        {
            alert('Size in bytes: ' + obj.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    }
};

obj.send(null);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Good answers will include an explanation of what was wrong and how you fixed it rather than just a code block that requires the reader to try to figure out what you changed.